# What does "speech time" mean?

Tags: terminology, tense

> **Tense** is the grammatical expression of the location of events in time. It anchors (or ‘grounds’) an event to the speaker’s experience
>   of the world by relating the **event time** to a point of reference.
>   The normal, universal and therefore unmarked point of reference is the
>   moment of speaking – **speech time**, what has been called ‘the
>   inescapable and constantly changing **now** in which all verbal
>   interaction takes place’. Past event takes place before the ‘now’,
>   while future events are thought of as taking place after it. (Angela
>   Downing, English Grammar: A University Course)

I don’t grasp what she says about the tense exactly. So I brought an example below. In the example, it seems that the ‘speech time’ is past, for the whole story is mainly developed by the tense. Having thought this, I’m confused at the ‘present’ dialogues: “I think you must. . .”, “See? Harry Potter. . .” 
Would you let me know what is ‘speech time’, and why it can be constantly changing now?

> "Hagrid," he said quietly, "I think you must have made a mistake. I
>   don't think I can be a wizard." 
>   To his surprise, Hagrid
>   chuckled. 
>   "Not a wizard, eh? Never made things happen when you
>   was scared or angry?" 
>   Harry looked into the fire. Now he came
>   to think about it... every odd thing that had ever made his aunt and
>   uncle furious with him had happened when he, Harry, had been upset or
>   angry... chased by Dudley's gang, he had somehow found himself out of
>   their reach... dreading going to school with that ridiculous haircut,
>   he'd managed to make it grow back... and the very last time Dudley had
>   hit him, hadn't he got his revenge, without even realizing he was
>   doing it? Hadn't he set a boa constrictor on him? 
>    Harry looked
>   back at Hagrid, smiling, and saw that Hagrid was positively beaming at
>   him. 
>       "See?" said Hagrid. "Harry Potter, not a wizard - you wait, you'll be right famous at Hogwarts."  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Comment: To be honest, this is the type of question I'm surprised not everyone already knows the answer to and I thought about flagging the question to be closed. But the more I thought about it, unless someone teaches you something first, we can't really expect you to know it. Especially with a concept this fundamental to languages, we should encourage people to speak up if they don't understand something.

Comment: @acattle,  
Thank you very much: if you had closed this question, I might have wandered along. Even into the ELU, receiving the sort of sarcastic attacks, with mean words, for not knowing the fundamental things, positively – I do not know why the kind of guys doing answering activities not encourage people to speak. You’ve solved my age-old question.

Comment: @acattle:   Very true, sir!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's related to the concept of time. You know how **the present** refers to the exact moment we live in? Everything after it (i.e. everything that hasn't happened yet) is called **the future** and everything before it (i.e. everything that has already happened) is called **the past**. Also, you need to realize that the future will eventually become the past.

For example, image it's currently Wednesday. Today, Wednesday, is the present. Yesterday, Tuesday, is the past and tomorrow, Thursday, is the future. Now imagine it's Thursday. Is Thursday still the future? No, it's now the present. And when it becomes Friday then Thursday will be the past. So *on Wednesday* Thursday was "the future" but *on Friday*, Thursday is "the past".

**Speech time** (which I'd probably write as "time of speech") refers to the exact moment a person speaks/writes anything. **Tense** tells use when an event is happening in relation to when the person is speaking. So *on Wednesday*, I would use *future tense* to talk about events on Thursday (e.g. "I **will** go to the store on Thursday"). *On Friday* I need to use *past tense* to talk about Thursday (e.g. "I **went** to the store on Thursday").

Here is where is gets tricky and here is where I think your problem is: If it is Wednesday and I am talking about Thursday I must use the future tense *but* what if I wrote my message, "I will go to the store on Thursday", in an email and sent it to you but you didn't read it until Friday? *To you* Thursday is in the past but I still used future tense. The reason is that  at the time I wrote the message (the **speech time**) Thursday (when the **event** was to take place) was still in the future. However, time moved forward and by the time *you* read it, Thursday was in the past. However, this does not affect the grammatical of my message at all.

In the context of the Harry Potter quote, *the story* takes place in the past. That is why *the narrator* (the person telling the story to you, the reader) uses past tense. But the *events* the characters talk about are happening *at the same time as they are speaking about them* (i.e. the **event time** is the same as the **speech time**) so even though to you, the reader, the events are all in the past, the characters must use present or future tense because *to them* the events either are happening at that moment or have yet to happen.

In summary, tense is decided by the *temporal relationship* between when a **speech** is made (the **speech time**) and when the **event** it talks about takes place (the **event time**). The three simplest of these are past, present, and future.

Obviously tenses are more complicated than just past, present, future. Once you feel you understand the basic principle, check out [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_tenses) for more information on Tenses in English.

Comment: There's also **decoding time**, which in many languages is related to tense use in correspondence. I.e, in Latin one has the choice of using a present tense to refer to the time when the recipient reads it, and a past tense for the **coding** time (= speech time, but for writing). More details in [Fillmore's _Time_ lecture](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3-Time.pdf)

Comment: @jlawler Ya, I originally wrote that the time the listener hears the speech doesn't matter but I tried to edit that out after thinking about things as simple as English's future-perfect tense ("I will have been to the store"). Tense is definitely a complicated system.

Comment: Luckily, English has no future perfect tense; but modals are even more complicated than tense.

Comment: @jlawler Well, technically "perfect" is an aspect but in common usage "tense" is the used interchangeably with "inflection". I should have said "future-perfect inflection" but I wanted to keep the vocabulary simple considering this question will be most useful to beginners.

Comment: There's only one inflection in a so-called "future perfect" construction, and it's the past participle. It consists of an uninflected modal auxiliary followed by an uninflected infinitive followed by a past participle. If

Comment: I guess I better run along now.